# zipping the file through Java

Tags: java, zip

I am creating a .csv file and it is get created at the specified loaction , now I want to zip that file in the same location ,
so for this I was thing a to make a seprate method which will take the location where to be zipped file kept and the filename as a parameter please advise how to make this method and have the zipping logic , I have tried this..

```
File file = new File(Path + s) //path contain the location of file and s contain the filename
for (File f : new File(mcrpFilePath).listFiles()) { 

if (f.getName().endsWith(".csv")) { 
if (f.isFile()  && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
f.delete();
}
}
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
fileOutput));
addContent(aalist, bblist, bw);// seprate method that is writing in csv file
bw.close(); 
fileOutput.close();

// ???? Now here i want to call my zipp method seprately

   zipafile(Path + s) //?? what will be logic inside this method to zip the file
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MattClark pls advisefor the logic , I am stuck up on this,Thanks in advance

Comment: @SoniSahai There are Direct Classes to achieve this

Comment: You don't need to call 'File.delete()' or 'File.createNewFile()' or any of the tests that lead to those calls. 'new FileOutputStream() is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is   [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)  which takes  `FileOutputStream`  instance and give you the Zip file format.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
```

Checkout [Java.uti.Zip package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

[An Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/)